# how to update a css class dynamically onclick a dropdown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a dropdown with multi select enable.I am able to retrieve a value from the dropdown and am passing the value to css class.
ex:
        Andorra
        United Arab Emirates
        Afghanistan
        Antigua and Barbuda

am retrieving the country code from the drop down using

```
$( this).val()
```

i have a seperate div to show the flags where i have an li to display the flag

```
      <div class="flag">
                <li class="flag selected "+<append country code here></li>
             </div>
```

the issue am facing is when i use addClass(value) onchange event.it starts appending to the existing class.But, i need to clear the existing country code and append new one

my script is

```
 $('#test').on('change', function() {
  $('li').addClass($( this).val())
    });
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: * #test is dropdown id

Comment: How can you append `li` inside `div` without `ul`??

Comment: ↑↑↑ Ya, this is invalid HTML markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all the classes with `$('li').removeClass()` and then add the three classes: `$('li').addClass("flag selected " + $(this).val())`

```
$('li')
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("flag selected " + $(this).val());
```

Alternatively, you can save the previous class in a variable, and use `.removeClass(previousCountryClass)`.

**BTW** - `$("li")` is way too-general. You should probably add a unique `id` to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Try any one of below solutions.

Solution one Using **.removeAttr()**

```
  $('#test').on('change', function() {
      $('li').removeAttr( "class" );
      $('li').addClass("flag selected"+$( this).val());
  });
```

Solution two Using **.removeClass()**

```
  $('#test').on('change', function() {
      $('li').removeClass();
      $('li').addClass("flag selected"+$( this).val());
  });
```